java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthAggregator Upgrading spring-boot version from 2.3.12 RE to 2.7.18
This is the error I am getting failing to load application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator`

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthAggregator

These are the versions that I am upgrading to
Upgrading from spring-boot 2.3.12 RELEASE to 2.7.18
and spring-cloud Hoxton SR12 to 2021.0.8
What should be the solution for this?

It has been remove in 2.4, you need to use StatusAgregator

We aren't using it explicitly anywhere then why it is giving this error?

please give us the pom.xml and any custom health check code if you have any. It might be OrderedHealthAggregator or AbstractHealthAggregator you have

The error you're encountering is because the HealthAggregator class, which was present in Spring Boot 2.3.x, is no longer available in Spring Boot 2.7.x. In Spring Boot 2.2.x and earlier versions, HealthAggregator was used to aggregate multiple Health instances into a single overall Health status. From Spring Boot 2.2 onwards, this mechanism was replaced by HealthContributor and HealthIndicator interfaces to provide a more flexible way to contribute to the overall health status.
Given you are upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.x, you need to adjust your health check configurations and custom health indicators to use the new API.
